# Cannot get BibTex to generate references using TexStudio!

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, texstudio

I am aware that this question has been asked a million times before but whenever I try and run PDF Latex on **TexStudio** "Qt version 5.7.1" the pdf doesn't do any in-text referencing, instead there are just question marks.

I believe I have put my .bib file in the correct location and I am running the correct sequence of programs: PdfLatex -> BibTex -> PdfLatex-> PdfLatex. I've edited the build command to do this:

[image: Screenshot of TexStudio "Qt version 5.7.1" Preferences]

The files originally come from a thesis template on ?intended for? Overleaf: 
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-western-australia-uwa-phd-thesis-template/xnjfhjzqfghj#.WqrJlZOuxJw

The template referencing works as is on Overleaf but did not work on TexStudio, since then I have made very minor changes to this template (I downloaded a new one to use just for working out what this problem was, hence the name "test" everywhere) like shifting my .bib file up a level and changing its name.

The structure of the thesis has a mainTest.tex file which then \include 's the various chapters, each chapter then hosts a \bibliography and \bibliographystyle command. I've included the code since there isn't very much of it.

Main: "mainTest.tex"

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% NOTE: THIS IS A ROUGH TEMPLATE THAT WILL MOST LIKELY NEED CHANGES TO
% CONFORM TO YOUR INDIVIDUAL SITUATION
% THERE IS NO GUARANTEE OF ACCURACY OR COMPLETENESS TO THE TEMPLATE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,final,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
                            citecolor=black,
                            linkcolor=black,
                            urlcolor=red,
                            linktocpage=true,
                            hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}

\usepackage[square,sort,numbers,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\setlength\bibhang{.3in}


\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
% For electronic submission use:
\usepackage[inner=2cm,outer=2cm,top=2cm=bottom=2cm]{geometry}
% For printing use:
%\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm,top=2cm=bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbibind}


\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter. #1 }}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand\frontmatter{\pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}}

\newenvironment{chapabstract}{%
    \begin{center}%
        \singlespacing
        \bfseries ABSTRACT
    \end{center}}%

\begin{document}

%   \layout
    \begin{titlepage}
        \centering
        \vfill
        \textit{This thesis is presented for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy of The University of Western Australia}\\
        \vskip 1cm
        {\bfseries\Large
                A Very Good Thesis \\}

        \vskip1.5cm

%       \includegraphics[width=.40\linewidth]{UWAnew.jpg}
        \vskip 2cm  
        Student Full Name\\
        B.Sc. in FieldA; B.Sc. in FieldB; M.Sc in FieldC \\
        February 2016\\
        \vskip .5cm
        Center1\\
        Centre2\\
        SchoolA\\
%%      \vskip 1.5cm
%       \textbf{Supervisors:} 
%           Dr. FirstName LastName (Coordinating)\\
%           Prof. Dr. FirstName LastName\\
%           Prof. Dr. FirstName LastName\\
%           Prof. Dr. FirstName LastName\\
    \end{titlepage}
    %\maketitle
    \frontmatter
%   \linenumbers
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \phantom{a}
    \vfill
    \vfill

    \include{Declaration/declaration}

    %\include{Acknowledgments/acknowledgements}

   % \include{Declaration/author_declaration}

    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \mainmatter
    \raggedbottom
    \include{Chapter_1/Test}
    %\include{Chapter_2/Theory}
    %\include{Chapter_3/Methods}
    %\include{Chapter_4/Numerical}
    %\include{Chapter_5/Data}   
    %\include{Chapter_6/Results}    
    %\include{Chapter_7/Conclusions}    

\end{document}
```

Chapter: "Test.tex"

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{chapabstract}

Intro intro intro.

\end{chapabstract}

\section{Figures}
Reference Figure \ref{fig:Fig1}.

\subsection{This is a subsection}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{Chapter_1/Figs/Fig1.pdf}
    \caption[TOC Figure Description]{Caption.}
    \label{fig:Fig1}
\end{figure}
\subsubsection{This is a subsubsection}
Citations are like \cite{goossens93,AbedonHymanThomas2003}.  Or maybe \cite{Abedon1994} said something.  Or \cite{Cerveny} which is an example of how to make a bib file that includes an author whose name begins with a non-English character and \cite{forgues96}: an example of referencing a Ph.D. thesis and yet more non-English characters.



\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 
\bibliography{Testbib}
```

I'm using macOS High Sierra. The main file and .bib file "Testbib.bib" are in the same directory and the chapters are in the sub-directory chapter_1/Test.tex , I get numerous warnings from the log but am not sure what to make of them.

[image: Issues from log]

Also see:

**mainTest.bbl**

```
\newcommand{\SortNoop}[1]{}
\begin{thebibliography}{5}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[Abedon(1994)]{Abedon1994}
S.~T. Abedon.
\newblock Lysis and the interaction between free phages and infected cells.
\newblock In J.~D.~K. Karam, J.~W. Drake, K.~N. Kreuzer, G.~Mosig, D.~Hall,
  F.~A. Eiserling, L.~W. Black, E.~Kutter, K.~Carlson, E.~S. Miller, and
  E.~Spicer, editors, \emph{Molecular biology of bacteriophage T4}, pages
  397--405. ASM Press, Washington DC, 1994.

\bibitem[Abedon et~al.(2003)Abedon, Hyman, and Thomas]{AbedonHymanThomas2003}
S.~T. Abedon, P.~Hyman, and C.~Thomas.
\newblock Experimental examination of bacteriophage latent-period evolution as
  a response to bacterial availability.
\newblock \emph{Applied and Environmental Microbiology}, 69:\penalty0
  7499--7506, 2003.

\bibitem[{\SortNoop{Cerveny}}\v{C}erven\'{y}(2000)]{Cerveny}
V.~{\SortNoop{Cerveny}}\v{C}erven\'{y}.
\newblock \emph{Seismic Ray Method}.
\newblock Cambridge University Press, 2000.

\bibitem[Forgues(1996)]{forgues96}
E.~Forgues.
\newblock \emph{Inversion linearis\'ee multi-param\`etres via la th\'eorie des
  rais}.
\newblock PhD thesis, Institut Fran\c{c}ais du P\'etrole - University Paris
  VII, 1996.

\bibitem[Goossens et~al.(1993)Goossens, Mittelbach, and Samarin]{goossens93}
M.~Goossens, F.~Mittelbach, and A.~Samarin.
\newblock \emph{The LaTeX Companion}.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.

\end{thebibliography}
```

**mainTest.blg**

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
Capacity: max_strings=35307, hash_size=35307, hash_prime=30011
The top-level auxiliary file: mainTest.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Declaration/declaration.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapter_1/Test.aux
The style file: abbrvnat.bst
Database file #1: Testbib.bib
You've used 5 entries,
            2773 wiz_defined-function locations,
            629 strings with 5639 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 2215 in all, are:
= -- 184
> -- 125
< -- 4
+ -- 43
- -- 38
* -- 167
:= -- 360
add.period$ -- 16
call.type$ -- 5
change.case$ -- 21
chr.to.int$ -- 5
cite$ -- 10
duplicate$ -- 111
empty$ -- 184
format.name$ -- 43
if$ -- 456
int.to.chr$ -- 1
int.to.str$ -- 1
missing$ -- 6
newline$ -- 34
num.names$ -- 22
pop$ -- 54
preamble$ -- 2
purify$ -- 19
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 77
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 73
swap$ -- 14
text.length$ -- 1
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 45
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 21
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 73
```

Sorry if I've included too much info explicitly, I'm not exactly sure what's relevant. Please let me know ideas you have about what the problem is,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to run bibtex on each included file, not on the main file.